# how to debug this UnboundLocalError at /register/ local variable 'form' referenced before assignment?

Tags: django

```
from django.shortcuts import render , redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages

def register(request):

    if request.method =='POST':
       form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_vali`enter code here`d():
            username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('subject_home')
       else:                                                                           
            form =  UserCreationForm(None)     

    return render (request,'user/register.html',{'form':form})
```

UnboundLocalError at /register/ local variable 'form' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

correct the indentation of the code

```
def register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
       form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
            username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('subject_home')
       # this else is optional
       else: 
            messages.error(request, 'not valid')
    else:                                                                           
         form =  UserCreationForm()     
    return render (request,'user/register.html',{'form':form})
```